# Which IIS log would I see a log for index.html appearing in?

Tags: iis, iis-logs

I have a static site, with nothing but an index.html page.  When I hit it I can't see any change in the logs though.

1. Should I be seeing something in the logs?
2. If so, where\what should I see?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IIS you are using. Assuming 7.5 or above (> Windows 2008 r2), the default log location for IIS is **C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles** . Inside this all the folders are named in format W3SVC*siteID*, for example - W3SVC1. W3SVC2 etc.

In order to find the site ID

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Expand server node
3. Click on Sites

In the center pane (also know as workspace) you can see site name and it's ID.

Now usually when you browse a page in IIS something like below gets logged

```
2016-02-21 00:18:27 ::1 GET /index.html - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+rv:44.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/44.0 200 0 0 75
```

However you wont see this immediately in log file as IIS buffers that in memory and flushes it later. If you want to forcefully flush the buffer to log file you can run below command from a elevated command prompt

```
netsh http flush logbuffer
```

Hope this helps!